# Is there a difference between ECMA-335 and ISO/IEC 23271:2006? Also, is there a book version?

Tags: .net, command-line-interface, cil

The .net CLI is standardized as both [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) and [ISO/IEC 23271:2006](http://isotc.iso.ch/livelink/livelink/fetch/2000/2489/Ittf_Home/PubliclyAvailableStandards.htm) - is it 100% the same standard, or are there differences between these two?

Also, is the standard available as a book? Makes it easier to read :)

Comment: Every chapter in every partition has the exact same page number.  Fast-track ISO approval, it merely took them some time to change the copyright notices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mono's mirror](http://mono-project.com/ECMA-335-CLI-Public-Draft) of the draft of the next edition of the ECMA standard includes this historical context (emphasis mine):

> Since the initial submission, various Ecma member companies and individual contributors have produced two editions of the CLI standard, one in 2002 and one in 2006. Each Ecma edition was also submitted and approved by the International Standards Organization (ISO), specifically ISO/IEC JTC 1. The Ecma CLI specification went through the ISO/IEC JTC 1 Fast-Track process and the resulting document is referred to as ISO/IEC 23271. **Because Ecma adopts the equivalent ISO document as another edition, the Ecma-335 CLI standard is officially at its 4th edition as of June 2006.**

Answer (score 2):

An [annotated version of the original standard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321154932) was published years ago. (I have a copy, and I agree a physical book is a much better experience.) I do not think any of the later versions have been published on paper, though I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Ohh, Nice. Grabbed it from Amazon (ISBN 0-321-15493-2)

Answer (score 1):

From [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm):

> This Ecma publication is also approved as ISO/IEC 23271:2006

That strongly suggests that they're identical.

Comment: I know, but often the Devil is in the Details and I would hate it to find out that there is a minor difference that screws my application in production :)

Comment: The sole differences between ECMA 335 and ISO 23271, as I understand it (not having actually diff'ed the two _corpora_) are minor changes required to bring the former into conformance with ISO editorial and style standards. Whether those changes alter the meaning of the text in some significant way...I'll leave that to the language lawyers (which see the Jargon File at http://catb.org/jargon/html/L/language-lawyer.html).